# flask and socket io

Tags: python, sockets, flask

i am experimenting with flask and have a basic web page setup that gives me a data field to fill in. it all works ok, but i am having a problem with sending data via a socket connection to a server. the code is below:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import socket
import sys

app = Flask(__name__)

app.static_folder = 'static'

HOST, PORT = '', 8888


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/success', methods=['POST'])
def success():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['Update'] == 'Update':
            messsage_name = request.form["message_name"]

            with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as soc:
                # connect to server if we have a post
                soc.connect((HOST, PORT))
                soc.sendall(bytes(messsage_name + "\n", "utf-8"))
    return render_template("index.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

I want to open the socket once then send data via it each time the update button is pressed, at present the only way i can get it to work is keep opening the socket as in the above code in success. I don't want the socket to close until the flask app quits.

whats the best way to achieve my goal

thanks

Comment: I tried but could not understand what you actually want. Can you try again?

Answer (score 2):

I think your title is wrong. In your example there is no use of socketIO library.
For using socketIO in your flask application, you need to install the library like this:

```
pip install flask-socketio
```

And then you can import it in your python file as:

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
```

You can then use socketIO and emit some messages/data to your web page.

By the way your sockets, initialized as before, will live as long as your Flask server is on. More information available [over there.](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent)

If your goal is to use the Python sockets, then you have to edit your question title.